# Matlab code that iterates to solution using initial guess value

Tags: matlab, iteration

I have an application where I need to use an iterative technique to solve for a variable.  Basically I need to guess a value for a that will let K = 1.2;  Here are the parameters and equations that I have:

```
b = .02;
M = 3;
Sg = 4.5;
```

Here are the equations:

```
X = pi*alpha/2;
F = sqrt((1/X)*tan(X))*(.923 + .199*(1 - sin(X))^4)/cos(X);
K = F*Sg*sqrt(pi*a)
```

When I guess a value of .010125 I get the proper value of 1.2 for K.
How can I obtain the proper value of .010125 for a using an iterative technique with an initial guess value?

Here is entire code:

```
%ABS Plastic Under Moment Load
clc
clear all
% We need to guess a value to get K = 1.2
a = .010125; % guess this value
b = .02;
M = 3;
Sg = 4.5;
alpha = a/b;
X = pi*alpha/2;
F = sqrt((1/X)*tan(X))*(.923 + .199*(1 - sin(X))^4)/cos(X);
K = F*Sg*sqrt(pi*a)
```

Comment: You need to learn about iterative techniques then! The most basic one is Bisection, more complex one such as Newtons methods exist. Try to have alook at `fsolve`

Comment: thanks! looks like fsolve is a good option!

Answer (score 0):

Use `fsolve` to solve something as non-linear as that:

```
clc
clear all
% We need to guess a value to get K = 1.2
a = .010125; % guess this value
b = .02;
M = 3;
Sg = 4.5;
alpha = a/b;
X = pi*alpha/2;
F = @(X)sqrt((1./X).*tan(X)).*(.923 + .199*(1 - sin(X)).^4)./cos(X)-1.2/(Sg*sqrt(pi*a));
plot(0:0.01:1, F(0:0.01:1));

fsolve(F,X)
```

Note that I changed the definition on `F` to include the constrain, i.g. `F=0` will give the point where `K=1.2`

I get:

```
ans =

         0.795259758834974
```

**EDIT:**

If you are solving for `a`: Subsitute `X` by `(pi*(a./b)/2)` in the equations and solve. Note this is a very non-linear equation, it will fail unless given a good initial condition

```
F = @(a)sqrt((1./(pi*(a./b)/2)).*tan((pi*(a./b)/2))).*(.923 + .199*(1 - sin((pi*(a./b)/2))).^4)./cos((pi*(a./b)/2))-1.2./(Sg*sqrt(pi*a));
a=0.01
fsolve(F,a)
% or as  horchler Suggests
fzero(F,a)
```

Comment: `fzero` would be a better choice for univariate problem like this.